# `OperationProcessingError: unexpected ID Token "nonce" claim value` using auth.js, sveltekit, and the slack provider

Tags: sveltekit, next-auth

I was following this example: https://github.com/nextauthjs/sveltekit-auth-example, and it worked great.

Then, I added the Slack provider to `hooks.server.ts`:

```
export const handle = SvelteKitAuth({
  providers: [
    //@ts-expect-error issue https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6174
    GitHub({ clientId: GITHUB_ID, clientSecret: GITHUB_SECRET }),
    //@ts-expect-error issue https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6174
    Slack({clientId: SLACK_CLIENT_ID, clientSecret: SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET}),
  ]
})
```

and updated `vite.config.ts` to use https:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit(), basicSsl()],
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    },
  server: {https: true}
});
```

Now I get the following error when trying to login with slack:

```
[auth][error][CallbackRouteError]: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
[auth][cause]: OperationProcessingError: unexpected ID Token "nonce" claim value
    at Module.processAuthorizationCodeOpenIDResponse (file:///home/ubuntu/dev/auth.js/node_modules/oauth4webapi/build/index.js:1037:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async handleOAuth (file:///home/ubuntu/dev/auth.js/node_modules/@auth/sveltekit/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:79:24)
    at async Module.callback (file:///home/ubuntu/dev/auth.js/node_modules/@auth/sveltekit/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/routes/callback.js:14:41)
    at async AuthInternal (file:///home/ubuntu/dev/auth.js/node_modules/@auth/sveltekit/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:64:38)
    at async Proxy.Auth (file:///home/ubuntu/dev/auth.js/node_modules/@auth/sveltekit/node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:100:30)
    at async Module.respond (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:259:20)
    at async file:///home/ubuntu/dev/auth.js/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:506:22
[auth][details]: {
  "provider": "slack"
}
```